# TextInput dataDetectorTypes as PhoneNumber Issue

Tags: react-native, datadetectortypes

```
  <TextInput
        dataDetectorTypes={'phoneNumber'}
        editable={false}
        multiline
{...this.props}
      >
        {898989898}
      </TextInput>
```

When I use multiple TextInput on the same page with datadetectorTypes and if that is phoneNumber. And when I click on any number then ActionSheet will appear with Three options "Copy", "Send Message", "Add To Contacts" then all others numbers colour is getting changed on the same page. How can I fix this?

install Expo in iphone or ipad and after that click on below url

https://repl.it/@AnandNeema/PleasantBarrenTransversal

and then long press on number then color of other no that is on the page will change.

Comment: phonenumbers isn't an accepted type shouldn't work as it is use instead  phoneNumber

Comment: @CladClad
  i have used that one Only.

Comment: The issue doesn't occur for me.  Also the code snippet share is syntactically wrong, since `<TextInput/>` won't accept raw `text`. You might need to share the full code for the error to be resolved.

Comment: @PritishVaidya https://repl.it/@AnandNeema/PleasantBarrenTransversal